# Dodging a Caitlyn's Ace in the Hole

Tags: league-of-legends

Has anyone ever tried to flash *behind* the incoming projectile to dodge it? I haven't found anything related to this, maybe someone here knows if this is possible.

Comment: I've used this ability on an enemy as they just as they recalled before, and the bullet just followed them all the way to the fountain.  I would think that if you tried to flash or used a jump ability, the bullet would just turn and track you.

Comment: Darn, I was really hoping this was a thing, would be so much fun to do in a match. Thanks for the answers everyone!

Comment: It'd as much fun to do it to Nidalee's or Kalista's spear, that'll just keep on flying to it's max distance

Comment: except if you flash behind an ally champion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You won't be able to dodge the projectile by flashing over it. Once the shot is fired there is no way of dodging it by movement alone.

The only ways of dodging a Cait Ult are: Spellshields, stasis or someone standing between the initial target and the projectile.

Flashing behind the ult will merely cause it to change directions. The same happens if you are being teleported somewhere else.

Comment: Or becoming untargetable, e.g. Vlad Sanguine Pool, Fizz Playful/Trickster, Shaco Hallucinate, Zhonya's Hourglass active...

Comment: Also walls such as Anivia's or Yasuo's

Comment: @VedaadShakib w8, Anivia's wall can block Caith's ultimate skill? since when(what patch)?

Comment: Braums Shield can block it too

Comment: Braums shield and yasuo's windwall can block it. Anivia's cannot.

Comment: @ken Welp. My bad. I meant that many walls can also block the ult and was just giving a few examples.

Comment: Anivia's ult is made of minions.

Comment: Yorick's meatshield would do the trick ;)

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the game puts aside reality's physics, and since Caitlyn's Ace in the Hole isn't a skillshot ability, then it isn't dodgeable: it goes straight to the position you are (works as a homing shot).

You can only deny that damage by positioning right behind other friendly champions or Banshee's Veil spellshield.

Comment: Actually there are some non-skillshots that you can dodge.  You can actually dodge Poppy's E which is a targeted ability.

Answer (score 0):

In theory this could be possible as there are many non-skillshots that you can dodge. Examples being interrupting WW-ulti with Valkyrie and Alistar W with Buster Shot, Fiora dashing to avoid the dragon AA etc.

I played a Twisted Fate game a couple of days ago where I was locked on by Ace in the Hole and then teleported as it was airbound. It was completely negated. Unfortunantly I cannot be certain whether or not it hit one of my teammates on the way across the map, but from what my DuoQ parter could tell me it just disappeared. The enemy team also complained harshly as the ability would have killed me :)